# VSO Build vNext - Gated check-ins?

Tags: azure-devops

I have trawled the internet to find anything regarding gated check-in builds on Visual Studio Online's new Build vNext platform.

Does anyone know if this feature is supported?  I cannot find anything in the build options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gated checkins with TFVC and build vNext appear to now be available as of a March 3 2016 update in VSO/VSTS. Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/03/03/tfs-2015-rc2-and-vs-2015-update-2-rc-are-available/

They plan to be coming to on-premises in TFS 2015 Update 2. It's now available in RC2 per: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2016/03/03/tfs-2015-rc2-and-vs-2015-update-2-rc-are-available/

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the answer is No.

Gated builds are not yet available in build.Next, if you want to use it, you need to choose to use XAML builds.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/overview

Comment: is there any information or road map that would give us an idea of when gated check ins will become available?

Comment: @JonasStawski, no, there is no public official document about when it will be available. There is one feature request about it on the Microsoft UserVoice site, you can vote it: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/8775376-add-gated-check-in-support-in-build-vnext

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using branch policies can serve your requirement? You will need to configure some policies which will allow you to merge to master only via pull requests, you can also block the merge if the build is unsuccessful.. you can check more details here - http://techtwaddle.net/2015/07/13/branch-policies-in-visual-studio-online/

Comment: Unfortunately we are not using Git as our repository, but thanks.